# JavaScript Accessing Data From Imported Script

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to export/import script from model.js and I use this

```
import * as model from './model.js';
```

Here's the script of model.js

```
export const state = {
  recipe: {},
};
console.log(state.recipe);
export const loadRecipe = async function (id) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/v2/recipes/${id}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`${data.message} (${res.status})`);
    console.log(data);
    let { recipe } = data.data;
    console.log(recipe);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

This is the render part where I'm trying to access recipe part from model.js.

```
const showRecipe = async function () {
  try {
    const id = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    if (!id) return;
    renderSpinner(recipeContainer);
    //1.Loading Recipe
    await model.loadRecipe(id);
    const { recipe } = model.loadRecipe.recipe;
```

I'm trying to access recipe part here:
const { recipe } = model.loadRecipe;

But I'm getting undefined. Please help me identify the problem, is it exporting, importing or I'm accessing data in the wrong way? Also, how should I push the recipe part to the state recipe?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import the values from `model.js` separately.

```js
import { state, loadRecipe } from './model';
```

Then, you can read the `state` value after running the `loadRecipe()` method.

```js
// ...
await loadRecipe(id);
console.log(state.recipe);
```

But, I think you forget to set `recipe` value in `loadRecipe()` function in `model.js` too.

```js
// get the recipe ...
// then ...
state.recipe = recipe;
```

Comment: Yess state.recipe = recipe worked! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
export const state = {
  recipe: {},
};
console.log(state.recipe);
export const loadRecipe = async function (id) {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/v2/recipes/${id}`
    );
    const data = await res.json();
    if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`${data.message} (${res.status})`);
    console.log(data);
    state.recipe = data.data.recipe;
    console.log(recipe);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

```
await model.loadRecipe(id);
const { recipe } = model.state;
```

but why you dont want to return the data and save it to a variable instead? normally you will just return the recipe from the loadRecipe function.

Answer (score 0):

If you try it with vanilla JS:

```
// model.js
const loadRecipe = async function (id) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(
            `https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/v2/recipes/${id}`
        );
        const data = await res.json();
        if (!res.ok) throw new Error(`${data.message} (${res.status})`);
        console.log(data);
        let { recipe } = data.data;
        console.log(recipe);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

...in another file(call.js)...

```
const showRecipe = async function () {
    try {
        const id = window.location.hash.slice(1);
        if (!id) return;
        renderSpinner(recipeContainer);
        //1.Loading Recipe
        await model.loadRecipe(id);
        const { recipe } = model.loadRecipe.recipe;
```

...in your html file...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="model.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="call.js"></script>
```